# perl block of comma separated variables equals another block of comma separated values

Tags: perl

I am examining a perl script and have come across code such as the following in several places at the top of the script:

```
(
    $AllowFullYearView,          $LevelForRobotsDetection,
    $LevelForWormsDetection,     $LevelForBrowsersDetection,
    $LevelForOSDetection,        $LevelForRefererAnalyze,
    $LevelForFileTypesDetection, $LevelForSearchEnginesDetection,
    $LevelForKeywordsDetection
  )
  = ( 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 );
```

What means this?  My first thought was it was a shorthand way of setting values to the variables, however the number of elements in each block is not the same.

(Trying to describe the structure has made searching for the answer difficult.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an assignment: all elements from the left list get assigned the values from the right list. This is by position, element 1 in the left list gets the value from element 1 in the right list, and so on.

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2, 3);
print "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c\n";
```

This prints:

> a=1, b=2, c=3

Now when the right list has more elements than the left one, the extra elements are not used.

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
print "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c\n";
```

Still prints:

> a=1, b=2, c=3

If the left list has more elements, nothing gets assigned to the extra ones:

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2);
print "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c\n";
```

> Use of uninitialized value $c in concatenation (.) or string at lists.pl line 6.
> a=1, b=2, c=

where the warning is caused by `use warnings;` (which every program should have).
In your case, if list sizes are off, it probably means someone adjusted one list and forgot the other.

Hence a better way to this assignment would be individually:

```
my $AllowFullYearView = 2;
my $LevelForRobotsDetection = 2;
...
```

where it becomes obvious if values are missing or extra.

---

Copying lists is often used for parameters in a function:

```perl
sub foo {
    my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;
    ...
}
```

Here the `foo` function copies its first 3 arguments from the [`@_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub) array into the local variables `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`.